# LINQ multiple joins performance optimization

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq

I need to retrieve a list of orders records, and on the same view I have to show for each order:

- how many invoices have been issued (**InvoiceCount**)
- the total amount covered by the invoices (**Invoiced**)
- how much has been paid for the issued invoices (**Payed**)

all on the same grid view.

I think it's a basic view for business management software.

**Order** > **invoices** = one-to-many

**Payments** are related to **invoices** with a look-up table **PaymentsToInvoices**

GridView is paged server-side, with a page-size of 50 records.

I've written the following LINQ, that it works fine, but I have some doubt that is well written in terms of performance,
especially if this query is finally translated with a couple of sub-queries, that means 50*2 queries for each request!

```
var orders = (from o in db.Orders
  join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
  join os in db.OrderStatuses on o.OrderStatusID equals os.OrderStatusID
  join ps in db.PaymentStatuses on o.PaymentStatusID equals ps.PaymentStatusID
  join ec in db.EntryChannels on o.EntryChannelID equals ec.EntryChannelID

  orderby o.InsertDate descending
  where o.OrderStatusID == 2
  select new
  {
      o.OrderID,
      o.CustomerID,
      o.InsertDate,
      o.TotalPrice,
      o.Notes,
      c.FirstName,
      c.LastName,
      OrderStatus = os.Name,
      PaymentStatus = ps.Name,
      EntryChannel = ec.Name,
      InvoiceCount = (db.InvoiceDetails.Where(i => i.OrderID == o.OrderID).Select(s => s.InvoiceID).Distinct().Count()),
      Invoiced = (db.InvoiceDetails.Where(i => i.OrderID == o.OrderID).Select(s => s.TotalPrice).Sum()),
      Payed = (from py in db.Payments
               join pti in db.PaymentsToInvoices on py.PaymentID equals pti.PaymentID
               join inv in db.InvoiceDetails on pti.InvoiceID equals inv.InvoiceID
               where inv.OrderID==o.OrderID
               select new { py.PaymentID, py.Amount }).Distinct().Select(s=>s.Amount).Sum()
  });
```

What do you think about the last three fields? Can they be improved in some way? Do they result in performance killer sub-queries?